# How to find the sequences containing X consecutive 0's or 1's in a set of binary sequences?

Tags: oracle, search, binary

Given a set of bit sequences, what's the quickest way to find the ones which contain a given number of 0's? Is there a bitwise operation/mask operation I can use for this?

**Details:**

- All the sequences of bits have the same length (287).
- when I say "quickest" I mean performance wise, not the quickest to write/maintain.
- These sequences will actually be stored in individual records in Oracle and SQL Server, and this operation will probably be executed in a query, but I think I can implement it, once I understand the logic.

**Further details:**

This is a way to find availability in a booking system with performance constraints. The solution I thought was to store the availability as strings of bits or a number composed by 1's and 0's, each bit representing 5 minutes intervals.

When I have to find a slot of 30 minutes, I need to find 6 consecutive 0's. If you have better ideas, I would be very interested in exploring them.

Comment: "Booking intervals", "slot of 30 minutes" ... - why don't you use DATE datatype? Looks *natural* to me (while string of 287 bits doesn't). But hey, what do I know, just saying.

Comment: Hey! thanks for replying.
As I said, "If you have better ideas, I would be very interested in exploring them."

How would you implement this with datetimes?
I thought to use this representation to keep the availability for a single "day" on a single line, to improve performance, but I might be completely wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from my *ranting* as  a comment, see whether a simple `INSTR` helps. Sample data (didn't feel like typing 287 bits) from lines #1 - 4; query itself begins at line #5.

```
SQL> with test (id, col) as
  2    (select 1, '1011100001101001' from dual union all
  3     select 2, '1010101000000110' from dual
  4    )
  5  select *
  6  from test
  7  where instr(col, '000000') > 0;

        ID COL
---------- ----------------
         2 1010101000000110

SQL>
```

Comment: Turn out, String manipulation in Oracle is so optimized that even pattern searches have little cost and negligeble execution times.